# Media Query CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, width, developer-tools

```
    .contact-me h2 h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.contact-message{
  width: 80%;
}
```

**This is my code inside media query and Its width is not working can anyone help, please
I selected the same name of class but it didn't work

[This is the image from developer tools I incepted my site and found that in my media query .contact-message   width is been overridden by my .contact-message outside media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQsYj.png)**

Comment: Here there is an overlap of the css rules. Your media query must be below the basic rule in order.

Comment: It feels strange to have an h3 inside an h2 in `.contact-me h2 h3`

Comment: oh, I didn't know what does mean I thought I'm selecting both h2 and h3 from contact-me class, Should I use them separately?? @bron

Answer (score 0):

Your css is overlapping so use !important tag. So new code will be:

```css
.contact-message{
  width: 80%!important;
}
```